# How to edit apache config by php file

Tags: php

i've server without any control panel

and i am trying to build file that allow me to add subdomains to my site

by editing ( apache config file ) and ( named zones )

but i've no permissions to edit this files!!  i am only able to read them!

my example file is

mysite.com/panel/file.php

```
<?

    if ( $_GET['read_httpd']){

    $content = file_get_contents ( '/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf' );

    if ( !empty ( $content ) )

        echo 'File Read!<br />';

        echo $content;

    }

    elseif ( $_GET['remove_named'] ){

        $delete = unlink ( '/var/named/alaa.hosts' );

        }


    elseif ( $_GET['remove_config'] ){

        $delete = unlink ( '/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf' );

}


?>
```

i've been read files successfully, but i am unable to edit !!

So, How can i allow the file to edit?

Answer (score 3):

Seems like a rhetorical question, `i've no permissions to edit this files, How can i allow the file to edit?`.

What you could try is just leave the config files alone and if you can setup a wild-card sub-domain, use a url rewrite to route the different sub-domains to different locations / folders. The exact how-to would depend on the platform you are on.

Comment: You responded to a question that does not exist, my question is How to give access to the php to be able to edit the apache config file, your answer is more insulting than the benefit, thank you and i am sorry for my language

Comment: @Alaa Gamal I did not mean to insult, I just pointed out the contradiction in your question; if you don't have permissions to change a file, you cannot change it so you need an alternative solution, which I provided (although just the basic idea...).